# ipython/python console with my own parser/processor?

Tags: python, parsing, console, ipython

Is there an easy way to make ipython console redirect the cmd-line towards external parser and then output the result in the current session.

Say for example I have parser that calculates expressions (just for the sake of the example).
Then I want when the cmd-line starts with "calc:" to pass it to this external parser ... here is hypothetical example :

```
In[XX]: calc: 5 + 5
  external calc: 5 + 5 = 10
```

and so on, you get the idea..

---

this is the closest I found so far :
first create a shell script :

```
 #!/bin/sh
 echo $1
```

then in ipython :

```
 In [473]: !./x 123
 123
```

if it is in system path then even shorter :

```
 In [475]: !x 123
 123
```

Now if I can share state across invocations.

Comment: It's hard to implement new syntax with Python.  The `ipython` `%run` magic can pass commandline arguments to the script (after parsing it's own arguments like `-n`.  So if your 'parser' can be called from an OS shell, it can be called from `%run`.  `ipython` uses `argparse` to parse it's own commandline, and to handle the magic parameters.

Comment: will try that ... in general that is the idea I want to pass the whole line to the external parser and print back whatever the parser prints out. The problem with %run is that will become too much typing i.e. >%run script.py text<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work as extension :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from IPython.core.magic import (Magics, magics_class, line_magic, cell_magic, line_cell_magic)
from bi_lang import *

@magics_class
class BiMagics(Magics):

    def __init__(self, shell):
        super(BiMagics, self).__init__(shell)
        self.bi = BiLang()

    @line_magic
    def do(self, line):
        rv = self.bi.run(line)
        return rv

ip = get_ipython()
magics = BiMagics(ip)
ip.register_magics(magics)
```

Then :

```
 In [3]: %reload_ext ipython_extension
 In [4]: %do 5 + 6 
 ===== return ast =====
 Value
 +- val 11
 `- vtype 'num'
```

If you need more info, look here : 
http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html#defining-magics